# simplifing the code that would take out LCM

Tags: javascript, lcm

the following code is my original code i.e. i writed this code without copying others code or watching vedios to perform this function that would do the same. so what my code does is that, it would take out the LCM of any number:

**javascript**

```
     var number1_factors = [];

     var LCM = function(){

                number1_factors.length = 0;

                var number1 = document.getElementById("in1").value;



                var number1_array = number1.split('');

                    var sum = 0;                              
                            for (var i = 0; i < number1_array.length; i++) {  
                            sum += parseInt(number1_array[i],10);        
                    };


                if(number1 % 2 === 0){

                    for(number1 ; number1 % 2 == 0 ; ) 
                     { 
                        number1_factors.push(2);
                        number1 = number1 / 2;

                     }
                };

                if(sum % 3 === 0){
                   for(number1 ; number1 % 3 == 0 ; ) 
                     { 
                        number1_factors.push(3);
                        number1 = number1 / 3;

                     }
                };

                if ( number1 % 5 === 0 ){
                    for (number1 ; number1 % 5 == 0;){
                        number1_factors.push(5);
                        number1 = number1 / 5;
                    }
                };

                if( number1 % 7 === 0 ){
                                for (number1 ; number1 % 7 == 0;){
                        number1_factors.push(7);
                        number1 = number1 / 7;
                    }   
                }else{
                    number1_factors.push(parseInt(number1));
                };
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="in1" />
<input type="text" id="in2" />
<button onclick="LCM();">LCM</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

this code runs perfectly  but you know this function is too big, so i need to  simplify this code. is there any thing which i can do to reduce the size of this code?

thankyou for every sugestion.

Comment: I propose asking on CodeReview. See this checklist: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260427/2564301

Comment: No, this does not take out the LCM of *any* number. Try `121`.

Comment: this works.. i have seen results in google console. and what is `121`?